# How to pass data through url of ionic-plugin-deeplinks

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

```
.state('profiledet', {
    url: '/profiledet',
    params: { 'profile_id': null},
    templateUrl: 'templates/profile-det.html',
    controller: 'profiledet'
})
```

> above is the route of my page.

```
$cordovaDeeplinks.route({
  '/profiledet': {
    target: 'profiledet',
    parent: 'profiledet'
  }
})
```

> this is the deep linking route, I can't pass data through this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer, below is the code.

```
   $cordovaDeeplinks.route({'/profiledet:profile_id': {
target: 'profiledet',
parent: 'profiledet'
```

}
})